# What is the modern version of signal() system call?

Tags: linux, unix

I want to know what is the modern version of signal() system call.

Answer (score 0):

That would be [`sigaction`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html), a more flexible way of handling signals. Although it's a bit more effort to set up, it has distinct advantages over the older [`signal`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html) method.

You just have to look at that second link to see phrases like:

> When a signal occurs, and func points to a function, it is implementation-defined whether …
>
> … the behavior is undefined if the signal handler refers to any object other than `errno` …
>
> The `sigaction()` function provides a more comprehensive and reliable mechanism for controlling signals; new applications should use `sigaction()` rather than `signal()`.

This should hopefully convince you to use the more modern variant.